# How could I align my search engine like Google?

Tags: html, css

How does Google align its search engine? It seems that any screen resolution, the search bar is always center, with the logo above it and the buttons below it. I want my search engine to be the exact same, the only problem being that it seems to shift right on larger resolutions but fine on my Macbook Pro?

Any ideaS?
My CSS code is below:

```
.searching {
  position:relative;
  top:-60px;
  left:-30px;
  background-color:#EBEAE2;
  color:#000000;
  font-family:Trebuchet MS; 
  font-weight:normal; 
  font-size:16px; 
  width:800px;
}
.logo {
  posistion:relative;
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-left:270px;
}
.qlickbutton {
  position:relative;
  top:-42px;
  left:10px;
  height:50px;
  width:70px;
} 


<img src="Qlick1.png" class="logo" id="logo" width="600" height="300"> 

<form action='search2.php' method='get' autocomplete="off">
  <center> 
    <input class="searching" id="searching" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="k" maxlength="255">
    <input class="qlickbutton" id="qlickbutton" type="image" src="qlick button.png" alt="Qlick">
```

Comment: You can check CSS on google.com and see how they did it.

Answer (score 3):

Set your left/right margins to auto, and set a width on your div.

Also, if you ever want to know how another site does something, simply look at their source and/or inspect with your browser tools!

Comment: Try Opera. It has best inspecting tool called Butterfly.

Comment: @Kamil don't you mean Dragonfly?

Comment: Ouch, sorry :) Its Dragonfly indeed.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make it perfectly align in all browsers then go with percentages like

**HTML**

```
​<div id="main">
  <div id="searchName">your search engine name</div>
  <div id="searchEngine">SEARCH</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#main
{
  width:50%;
  margin:30% 25%; /* for alignment (set as you need)*/
}

#main div
{    
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}​
```

Or use positioning to achieve alignments.

My suggestion to you is that dont follow others designs. Create your own or understand it before implementing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Google aligns

```
center {
   text-align: -webkit-center;
}

<center>
    <div style="height:102px;"></div>
</center>
```

To see the full html\css source right click on the page and inspect the element with Chrome.